# Is it possible to get notification for development certificate build, in server side using production certificate

Tags: iphone

Just i wanted to know is it possible to get apple push notification service in developer certificate build, In server side they are using .p12 and .pem files are production server certificates and server side targeting to apple main APNS server, So in client side i need to test the notification service in my device. please suggest me is it possible or how can i test the notification service.

Answer (score 0):

You must use development-push certificates to test a app built with a development provision profile. Production-push certificates will only send notifications to apps build with ad hoc or AppStore provision profiles.